# Efficient responsive images with gulp

Tags: gulp, graphicsmagick, responsive-images

I am trying to efficiently generate responsive images for use on a website, but have some trouble with handling existing files and paths in gulp. The images reside in hierarchically structured folders, where `pages` is the root with several subfolders recursing downwards - most of which have images.

My current task looks like this:

```
gulp.task('responsive', function() {
    gulp.src('pages/**/*.{jpg,png}')
    .pipe($.plumber({
        errorHandler: function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            this.emit('end');
        }
    }))
    .pipe(responsive({
        '**/*.*': [{
            width: 2240,
            suffix: '-2240',
            quality: 70
        }, {
            width: 1920,
            suffix: '-1920',
            quality: 70
        }, {
            width: 1600,
            suffix: '-1600',
            quality: 70
        }, {
            width: 1280,
            suffix: '-1280',
            quality: 70
        }, {
            width: 1280,
            height: 300,
            crop: true,
            gravity: 'Center',
            suffix: '-thumbwide',
            quality: 70
        }, {
            width: 960,
            suffix: '-960',
            quality: 70
        }, {
            width: 640,
            suffix: '-640',
            quality: 70
        }, {
            width: 480,
            suffix: '-480',
            quality: 70
        }, {
            width: 320,
            suffix: '-320',
            quality: 70
        }]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(function(file) {
        return file.base;
    }));
});
```

There are two main issues with this:

1. Images are piped into the same folder as their source, when they would preferably be in an `images`-folder next to the source.
2. If the task is ran again, it generates new files based on both the sources and the previously generated responsive images.

The task uses [gulp-responsive-images](https://github.com/dcgauld/gulp-responsive-images), which leverages GraphicsMagick for the resizing. I tried using [gulp-changed](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-changed) (set as `.pipe($.cached('pages'))`)  to resolve issue 2, but it seemed to have no effect.

How can I resolve issue 1 and 2, based on my current setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to these two issues were the following:

1. Ignore the need for an `images`-folder. Rather, keep a separate `Source`-folder with neatly organized original images alongside text-files.
2. Use a temporary folder to ensure that the entire `output`-folder is rebuilt properly, with responsive images alongside text-files.

I wrote [a Gist](https://gist.github.com/OleVik/f2c8b51a7153743b13607072c27cf8d2) for it:

```
'use strict';
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');
var del = require('del');
var debug = require('gulp-debug');
var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

gulp.task('clean:output', function() {
    gutil.log('Deleting /output/**/*', gutil.colors.magenta('123'));
    return del([
        'output/**/*'
    ]);
});
gulp.task('build:source', ['clean:output'], function() {
    gutil.log('Build from /Source', gutil.colors.magenta('123'));
    return gulp.src(['Source/**/*'])
    .pipe(debug({title: 'Source:'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('output'));
});

gulp.task('build:responsive', ['build:source'], function() {
    return gulp.src(['output/**/*.{gif,jpg,jpeg,png}'])
    .pipe($.cached('responsive'))
    .pipe($.responsive({
        '**/*': [{
            width: 2240,
            height: 320,
            crop: 'center',
            rename: { suffix: '-thumbwide' }
        }, {
            width: 2240,
            rename: { suffix: '-2240' }
        }, {
            width: 1920,
            rename: { suffix: '-1920' }
        }, {
            width: 1600,
            rename: { suffix: '-1600' }
        }, {
            width: 1280,
            rename: { suffix: '-1280' }
        }, {
            width: 960,
            rename: { suffix: '-960' }
        }, {
            width: 640,
            rename: { suffix: '-640' }
        }, {
            width: 480,
            rename: { suffix: '-480' }
        }, {
            width: 320,
            rename: { suffix: '-320' }
        }, {
            width: 160,
            rename: { suffix: '-160' }
        }],
    }, {
        quality: 70,
        progressive: true,
        withMetadata: false,
        skipOnEnlargement: true,
        errorOnUnusedConfig: false,
        errorOnUnusedImage: false,
        errorOnEnlargement: false
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('responsive'))
});
gulp.task('build:images', ['build:responsive'], function() {
    gutil.log('Copying responsive images from /responsive to /output', gutil.colors.magenta('123'));
    return gulp.src('responsive/**/*.{gif,jpg,jpeg,png}')
    .pipe(debug({title: 'Images:'}))
    .pipe($.imagemin({
        progressive: true,
        interlaced: true
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('output'))
});
gulp.task('clean:responsive', ['build:images'], function() {
    gutil.log('Deleting /responsive/**/*', gutil.colors.magenta('123'));
    return del([
        'responsive/**/*'
    ]);
});

gulp.task('default', ['clean:output', 'build:source', 'build:responsive', 'build:images', 'clean:responsive']);
```

Using the following in packages.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "del": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-cached": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-debug": "^2.1.2",
    "gulp-gitignore": "^0.1.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.4.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-responsive": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

It takes files from `Source`, moves them to `output`, builds responsive images from the contents of `output` and stores them in `responsive`, then applies imagemin and moves them back into `output`. Finally, `responsive` is cleaned.